# Type Syntax error on token "=", Expression expected after this token (matrices multiplication)

Tags: java, matrix

I'm trying to create a method **produto** to multiply matrices that will not be received by user input so I put a some matrices examples to test the code inside main.
Right now I'm getting error "Syntax error on token "=", Expression expected after this token - line 15"
Any help?

```
public class Mmul {

public static void main(String[] args) {

double[][] A={{1,2},{2,3}};
double[][] B={{1,2},{2,3}};
double[][] C={{0,0},{0,0}};
}
public void produto(double A[][], double B[][]){

    int m=A.length; // numero de linhas da matriz A
    int p=A[0].length; // numero de colunas da matriz A
    int n=B[0].length; // numero de colunas da matriz B
    double[][] C=[m][n];

    if (A.length == 0 || B.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("A matriz nao pode ser calculada.");
        return;
            if (B.length != p){
                System.out.println("A matriz nao pode ser calculada.");
                return;
            }

        for (int i=0; i<m; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<n; j++){

                for (int k=0; k<p; k++) {
                    C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
                }
                }

            }
            for (int i=0; i<C.length; i++){
                for (int j=0; j<C.length; j++){
                    System.out.printf("\t %d \t",C[i][j]);
                    System.out.println();

                }

            }


    } // fim da verificacao das matrizes

// codigo do metodo produto

}
```

}

Comment: `double[][] C=[m][n];` is not an expression. How would you like to initialize `C`?

Comment: BTW that `return` statement before the 2nd `if` statement will cause that to be unreachable. Probably want to remove it or refactor...

Comment: I'll receive A and B from another program. I should create a bidimensional array (matrix C) to receive the result value of matrix A times matrix B. Now I see it really wasn't initialized :p
I'm afraid of adding values to it and my code not using the values that it will receive later.

Comment: Yeah, now I'm getting unreachable code error. I need the program to return null if the operation is not possible but I can't even write "return null" there. Where should "return null" go and what do you mean by refactor?

Comment: That's not possible unless you give your method a return type. We don't know what you intend the code to do. It could be that you need an else block - that where the refactor would come in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign to a type

```
double[][] c = new double[m][n];
```

Answer (score 0):

should replace:

double[][] C=[m][n];

with

double[][] C=new double[m][n];